# CPU processing in the code

Tags: c#, cpu-usage

How do I know how much CPU processing is using a certain routine in my code. This would be possible?
I can pick up using this as my program ...
using:

```
CpuUsage _cu = new CpuUsage();
cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_total";
string cpuUsage = _cu.GetUsage();
```

But have some way to get only a specific routine?

Comment: Your question is a bit "hand-wavy", but this may be helpful: [How to get CPU usage of processes and threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads)

Comment: In this case I can get as I'm using cpu in my case! but wanted something specific ... how to catch a routine of my code the CPU used. But I'll take a look at this link, thank you;)

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio Premium? That comes with [Performance Analysis Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) that will tell you all this and more.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have visual studio ultimate 2010 is the same thing?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you exactly what I wanted! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect a proper answer will include a write up on the performance monitoring tools in the latest Visual Studio.  In the mean time, I wonder if the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) might be useful?

```
var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
myFunctionToBeTimed();
Console.Writeline(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
```

Comment: That would measure clock time, but not the CPU processing for the particular task.

Comment: @TevoD.  That's true.  If `myFunctionToBeTimed()` is heavily I/O dependent it would return misleading results.  However, if the OP is looking to find out why his CPU is being pegged, it might be a useful quick & dirty tool.  A better answer would include how to use the Profiler / Perf analysis tools in Visual Studio, but I'm not prepared to provide that answer.

Comment: yes, in that case I could not measure the cpu usage = \ but it is something that can help me somehow.

Comment: in this case I think I can only get as was the cpu usage before my routine and soon after it.

Comment: ty @TevoD "Profiler / Perf analysis tools in Visual Studio" That's right, here's the answer to what I seek [Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). Ty

Answer (score 0):

Unless your code is waiting on IO, the CPU usage will be around 100% (of the core it's running on), right?